# tokenCan() method undefined

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I am currently following this tutorial,

https://nothingworks.netlify.app/blog/laravel-sanctum-multi-auth/

However when creating the middleware, the tokenCan method is undefined.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class CustomerMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->tokenCan('role:customer')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return response()->json('Not Authorized', 401);

    }
}
```

I have installed Laravel passport n sanctum, and I have ensured that my User model already calls use HasApiTokens. Please help me out, thank you

Comment: Check what return guard (dd(auth()->user())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `auth->user()` to `request->user()`.
From:

```
  if (auth()->user()->tokenCan('role:customer')) {
            return $next($request);
        }
```

To:

```
if ($request->user()->tokenCan('role:customer')) {
        return $next($request);
    }
```